# MVC form input button with name doesn't get submited

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a simple form which have name and age input boxes, at the bottom I have two buttons like:

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitAction" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitAction" value="Submit" />
```

The save button just creates a temporary data so they can come back and edit it, submit button will go ahead and create it, now when any of the buttons is clicked it goes to this controller function:

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson(Person model, string submitAction)
{
    //lots of code i removed
}
```

but the submitAction is null, any ideas on to why that is happening?

My full .cshtml code

```
@model Person

@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost(null, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBox(x => x.Name)
    @Html.TextBox(x => x.Age)

    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitAction" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitAction" value="Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `action at the form level`.Not at submit button

```
<form action="controller/action" method="post">

  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Save" />

</form>
```

It is better to use MVC built in HTML herlper classes like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: and where would I put this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the problem

Basically I had to change this

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitAction" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitAction" value="Submit" />
```

to this

```
<input type="submit" id="saveButton" name="submitAction" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" id="saveButton" name="submitAction" value="Submit" />
```

The submitButton didn't seem to post correctly :)